# listview shows first Item of cursor on every row

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

I have listView in my fragment i use a cursorAdapter to fill the list view but problem is Adapter shows first row data on every item if there are 3 items in cursor listview show three items but all are same i search a lot but i found nothing usefull
fragment:

```
public class ListPatientFragment extends Fragment  implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {                     

private PatientAdapter mPatientAdapter;
private ListView mListView;
private Button mAddButton;
private int mPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;
private static final String SELECTED_KEY = "selected_position";

public ListPatientFragment() {

}

public interface Callback {
    /**
     * DetailFragmentCallback for when an item has been selected.
     */
    public void onItemSelected(Uri dateUri);
}




private static final String[] FORECAST_COLUMNS = {

        MedicalContract.PropertyEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + MedicalContract.PropertyEntry._ID,
        MedicalContract.PropertyEntry.COLUMN_DATE,
        MedicalContract.PropertyEntry.COLUMN_SEX,
        MedicalContract.PropertyEntry.COLUMN_AGE,
        MedicalContract.PropertyEntry.COLUMN_CHIEF_COMPLIMENT,
        MedicalContract.PropertyEntry.COLUMN_RESIDENT_ILLNESS,
        MedicalContract.PatientEntry.COLUMN_PATIENT_SETTING,
        MedicalContract.PropertyEntry.COLUMN_NAME_KEY,
        MedicalContract.PatientEntry.COLUMN_PATIENT_IDENTIFICATION,
        MedicalContract.PatientEntry.COLUMN_PATIENT_SETTING,
        MedicalContract.PatientEntry.COLUMN_FIRST_NAME,
        MedicalContract.PatientEntry.COLUMN_LAST_NAME
};

static final int COL_PROPERTY_ID = 1;
static final int COL_DATE = 2;

static final int COL_SEX = 3;
// this is correct:
static final int COL_AGE = 4;
//this is correct:
static final int COL_RESIDENT_ILLNESS = 6;
//this is correct:
static final int COL_CHIEF_COMPLIMENT = 5;
static final int COL_PATIENT_IDENTIFICATION = 8;
static final int COL_PATIENT_SETTING = 9;
static final int COL_FIRST_NAME = 10;
static final int COL_LAST_NAME =11;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_patient, container, false);
    //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_patient, container, false);

    String sortOrder = MedicalContract.PropertyEntry.COLUMN_DATE + " DESC";
    Uri allPatientUri = MedicalContract.PropertyEntry.buildAllPatientList(System.currentTimeMillis());

    Cursor cur = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(allPatientUri,
            null, null, null, sortOrder);


    mPatientAdapter = new PatientAdapter(getActivity(), cur, 0);

    mListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.MainListOfAllPatients);
    mListView.setAdapter(mPatientAdapter);


    mAddButton =(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.New_Patient_Button);
    assert mAddButton !=null;
    mAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent MyIntent= new Intent (getActivity(),MedicalActivity.class);
            startActivity(MyIntent);
        }
    });


    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            // CursorAdapter returns a cursor at the correct position for getItem(), or null
            // if it cannot seek to that position.
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            if (cursor != null) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),cursor.getString(COL_DATE),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                String PatientIdentification = cursor.getString(COL_PATIENT_IDENTIFICATION);
                Long PatientDate=cursor.getLong(COL_PROPERTY_ID);
                ((Callback) getActivity())
                        .onItemSelected(MedicalContract.PropertyEntry.buildPropertyPatientWithDate(PatientIdentification,PatientDate));
            }
            mPosition = position;
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String sortOrder = MedicalContract.PropertyEntry.COLUMN_DATE + " DESC";

    Uri listOfAllPatientUri = MedicalContract.PropertyEntry.buildAllPatientList(System.currentTimeMillis());


    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
            listOfAllPatientUri,
            FORECAST_COLUMNS,
            null,
            null,
            sortOrder);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mPatientAdapter.swapCursor(data);

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

}
}
```

adapter:

```
     public class PatientAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
      public PatientAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
       super(context, c, flags);
    }
    public static class ViewHolder {
    public final ImageView iconView;
    public final TextView patientFirstNameView;
    public final TextView patientLastNameView;
    public final TextView patientAgeView;
    public final TextView patientResidentIllnessView;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        iconView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_icon);
        patientFirstNameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.patient_first_name);
        patientLastNameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.patient_last_name);
        patientAgeView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.patient_age);
        patientResidentIllnessView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.patient_resident_illness);
    }
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    int layoutId = -1;
    layoutId = R.layout.detail_list_patient;
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutId, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    view.setTag(viewHolder);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    if(cursor != null &&cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        String patientSex = cursor.getString(ListPatientFragment.COL_SEX);
        if (patientSex.equals("Male")) {
            viewHolder.iconView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_male_icon);
        } else if (patientSex.equals("Female")) {
            viewHolder.iconView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_female_icon);
        }

        String patientFirstName = cursor.getString(ListPatientFragment.COL_FIRST_NAME);
        viewHolder.patientFirstNameView.setText(patientFirstName);

        String patientLastName = cursor.getString(ListPatientFragment.COL_LAST_NAME);
        viewHolder.patientLastNameView.setText(patientLastName);

        String patientAge = cursor.getString(ListPatientFragment.COL_AGE);
        viewHolder.patientAgeView.setText(patientAge);

        String patientIllness = cursor.getString(ListPatientFragment.COL_RESIDENT_ILLNESS);
        viewHolder.patientResidentIllnessView.setText(patientIllness);
    }
}
        }
```

XML listView:

```
    <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/MainListOfAllPatients"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimaryLight"></ListView>
```

Comment: `if(cursor != null &&cursor.moveToFirst())` - Look in the `bindView()` method. Every time it's called, you're moving the `Cursor` to the first position. Don't do that. You don't really need the null check there, either.

Comment: yes that was the problem thank you very much...